# Will altering a column name in a MySQL master be replicated to the slave

Tags: replication, mysql-5.7

I have a replicated MySQL database that until recently was supported by a DBA. Unfortunately, he has now left so we're playing catch up.

From what I can tell the replication that is set up is:

- binary_log based (i.e. not GTID)
- row based
- the table being altered is InnoDB

I'm basing this on a few things

1. The output from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` references the binary log
2. The `mysql.gtid_executed` table on the master and slave are both empty
3. The output from `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';` is `ROW`

The master server is using MySQL version 5.7.9. The slave is using MySQL version 5.7.17

If I change a column name in the master database using the command

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN old_column_name new_column_name DATETIME NOT NULL
```

will the change be replicated to the slave?

Or do I need to change the column name in the slave as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to test this on our replicated environment.

Surprisingly, the column name was updated in the slave environment. I assumed this would not be the case because the row-based replication was configured.

Comment: In spite of using RBR, DDL statements need to be done as if SBR.  The guiding premise of Replication is that the Slave will always (with a slight delay) have exactly the same dataset as the Master.